# Remotely WIPE the Blackberry device?

Tags: blackberry

I am working on a security app in BB, in which I want to Wipe the data of my device in case of  emergency or for security purpose, but REMOTELY.

Is it possible to WIPE the data(EMAILS, CONTACTS, MESSAGES etc) from BB device remotely? Please suggest me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIM does not expose that functionality to user apps, but they have their own app for that purpose - [Blackberry Protect](http://www.blackberry.com/protect).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, there's no API available for that purpose.